# How to eliminate identifier while cogrouping in Pig

Tags: hadoop, join, null, apache-pig

I have 10 dataset to join.
When I use cogroup, what I get is below

```
(50637,22284),{(50637,22284,278)},{(50637,22284,308)},{},{},{},{},{},{(50637,22284,17)},{(50637,22284,5)},{(50637,22284,1)}
```

As seen, grouping identifier is duplicated in each parenthesis.
How can I get the output with the format below ?

```
(50637,22284,278,308,0,0,0,0,0,17,5,1)
```

Comment: perhaps, you can FLATTEN the tuples to bring the fields outside of tuples?

Answer (score 1):

Use FOREACH/GENERATE to select out the fields you want to keep. See http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.1/basic.html#foreach - Nested Projection

Comment: what I did
Y = foreach X generate $0,$1.$2,$2.$2,$3.$2,$4.$2,$5.$2,$6.$2,$7.$2,$8.$2,$9.$2,$10.$2,$11.$2,$12.$2,$13.$2,$14.$2;